# create a mySQL string that is derived from the index

Tags: mysql, insert

Is it possible to generate a string in mySQL that will include the auto incremented index?

the record would look like:

```
Index | generatedField
-----------------------
1     | random_Number_1
2     | random_Number_2
```

can I use it in an "Insert" comand? like that:

```
INSERT INTO CrB (generatedField) VALUES (  CONCAT(rand(),`Index`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know the auto_increment index before you insert the row. But you can do it with two statements:

```sql
INSERT INTO CurB (generatedField) VALUES ('');

UPDATE CurB 
SET generatedField = CONCAT(RAND(), '_', LAST_INSERT_ID())
WHERE `Index` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: so this actually means two different sql calls from my PHP?
(Or did you mean that I can somehow do it in one sql string?)

Comment: It's a question of your settings. You can pass two SQL statements in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
SELECT 
`Index`,
CONCAT('random_number_',`Index`) AS generatedField
FROM your_table;
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ba325/1/0)</kbd>

**EDIT:**

In order to insert random text in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE curB(
   randomNumberText VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO curB(randomNumberText) VALUES(CONCAT('random_number_',RAND()));
```

Comment: can I use it in an "Insert" comand? like that: 
INSERT INTO CurB (generatedField) VALUES (  RAND() +Index    );

Comment: Yes, it has "Index" colum that is automatically incrementer and it has "generatedField" culum. And I want to assign a value In the "generatedField", right away when the record is being created (and I want this record to be assembled from the value of the index that is being generated on the record creation, together with a random number)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  concat('random_number_', index) as generated_field from my_table;
```

and

```
insert into your_insert_table value(your_column)
select  concat('random_number_', index) as generated_field from my_table;
```

Comment: can I use it in an "Insert" comand? like that: 
INSERT INTO CurB (generatedField) VALUES (  RAND() +Index    );